# Where is the doc to explain the notation used in TCL command syntax

Tags: tcl

I am reading the on-line TCL command document, it uses things like ?argument?, ... and some font to designate some specific meaning, it is not hard to understand the notation, but I like to find the explanation doc of this notation, to my surprise, it is not easy to find it.

Could you give me a pointer?

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that I cannot find information about Tcl synopsis convention, but I will try my best to explain. For example, the synopsis for `puts` is:

**puts** ?**-nonewline**? ?*channelId*? *string*

In this context, the bold face means you need to type it verbatim (**puts** and **-nonewline**) and the italics are a varying argument (e.g., the *string* to print).

Arguments between question marks (which are not bold or italic, and do not actually form part of the argument) such as ?*channelId*? are optional.

Example use of `puts`, therefore, are:

```
puts "Hello, world"
puts $myChannel "Hello, world"
puts -nonewline "Please type your name: "
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In the online documentation the question marks around -nonewline are not bold and -nonewline is not italicized. Also, channelId and string are italicized which appears to mean - represents the actual word you will use.

Comment: Which online docs are you looking at? http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm has it bold. The dash is a literal dash, btw.

Comment: There have been builds of the docs in the past where the boldness and italicization were wrong in some places. I fixed them, but where people have a buggy copy I can't fix that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do not have problem understanding the notation. The reason I search for notation doc is we are trying to use TCL command notation to declare our domain language. Looks like I will need to go through all command doc pages to get a complete view.

Comment: The other notation you see very rarely is the use of `[`…`|`…`]` to indicate choices. The only manual page I can think of offhand that uses it is http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/memory.htm and I suppose it's composeable with `?`…`?` notation, though that's never come up for us.